# c#Repository pattern: One repository per subclass?

Tags: c#, repository-pattern

I am wondering if you would create a repository for each subclass of a domain model.
There are two classes for example:

```
public class Person
{
    public virtual String GivenName { set; get; }
    public virtual String FamilyName { set; get; }
    public virtual String EMailAdress { set; get; }    
}

public class Customer : Person
{
    public virtual DateTime RegistrationDate { get; set; }
    public virtual String Password { get; set; }        
}
```

Would you create both a PersonRepository and a CustomerRepository or just the PersonRepository which would also be able to execute Customer related queries?

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on how you domain works.  You would usually have one Repository for every [Aggregate Root](http://dddstepbystep.com/wikis/ddd/aggregate-root.aspx) (a DDD term meaning a parent entity, but not in the traditional inheritance way) of your domain.

If you really work with both Person and Customer as part of you domain, then a Repository for each is suitable.  A Repository does not need to have a heavy implementation, and Repositories can often share a lot of their implementation, especially when working with an ORM.

[This page](http://devlicio.us/blogs/casey/archive/2009/02/20/ddd-the-repository-pattern.aspx) is a good introduction to the aims of the repository pattern. The [Domain Driven Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design) approach is a good place to start.

Comment: The link to the repository pattern introduction seems to be broken. Could you provide a new source?